# How do I get cURL to return cyrillic characters in such a way, that I can proccess them with regex?

Tags: php, curl, cyrillic

I've written some cURL that pulls out a whole html page, however there is Cyrillic characters on that page and they do not get displayed or rather they all look like this ���������. I want to use regex to capture certain parts of the page but I can't do that without being able to read the Cyrillic.

So how do I get the cURL to return Cyrillic that I can use.

This is my cURL:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '$post');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, COOKIES_DIR.'$cookie_path');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIES_DIR.'$cookie_path');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I'm guessing I have to set some kind of cURL option but I do not know what that is.

Comment: Make sure you're displaying the characters in the right character set. If you look at the response headers or response HTML you should be able to figure out what the character set is.

Comment: @Halcyon I found this line in the response:

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">

Do I have to add something like this:

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array ("Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251"));

Would this do it?

Answer (score 1):

> Do I have to add something like this: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array ("Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251")); Would this do it?

It doesn't matter for CURL, it wont interpret the content.

If you want to run regular expressions on that string make sure the input regular expression is in the same character set. I would recommend to do this by changing the encoding of the response:

```
$w1251 = $reponse;
$utf8 = mb_convert_encoding($w1251, "UTF-8", "Windows-1251 (CP1251)");
```

If your PHP source code file is also in UTF-8 any special characters should match just fine.

Alternatively you could also change the characterset of the your source code, but I wouldn't recommend it as someone might accidentally convert it.

---

Similarly when you display the text (on an HTML page) make sure the character set matches that of the content.

If you wanted to display the w1251 content you can add a similar `meta` tag and the characters will show up correctly. You can also convert the string to utf-8 and add the meta tag for utf-8.

Comment: Its progress, but not quite there yet. Now instead of ���������, I get these: ãðàä Ñîôèÿ, Ëîçåíåö, 800 êâ.ì, Ïðåäëàãàìå âè êúùà â êâàðòàë Ëîçåíåö ñ îòëè÷íî. I'm guessing something in the encoding conversion, wasn't quite right. How do I check what it was exactly, or it might be the visualization of html. 

I do that by echoing the content I get from the curl. How do I add a meta tag to that? or do you mean I add it to the php file in which i'm echoing the html content?

Comment: Hmm yea, that doesn't look right at all. What you can do is open the request page yourself and save the HTML page to file. Then instead of doing the CURL request read the saved file. This removes a step. Also verify that you're using the correct encodings.

Comment: It does remove a step but its not really useful in the long run as this has to be an automated process when I'm done. I do all the display at this point just to make sure that it all works i.e. to catch problems like the one I'm having right now.

How do you suggest I verify that I'm using the correct encodings?

Comment: .. by downloading the file and checking. Removing the step is for debugging.

Comment: Sorry for being a dumbass, I'm quite new. I downloaded it and there is surprisingly little there, probably because its all of the actual info is behind a *.cgi. All I get from the downloaded page is this: `<html><head> <title>mask</title> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251"> </head> <frameset rows="0,*" frameborder="NO" border="0" framespacing="0"> <frame name="emptyframe" scrolling="NO" noresize="noresize"> <frame name="obiaviframe" src="obiavi.cgi?s0=&amp;s1="> </frameset> </html>`

Comment: That's weird. Is this the same response that CURL gets? Maybe CURL queries one of the frames instead? (ie. `obiavi.cgi?s0=&s1=`)

Comment: Hey thanks a lot man, everything worked when I used a different function iconv instead of mb_convert_encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Try following headers

```
$ch =  curl_init();

                $header[] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,";
                $header[] = "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
                $header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
                $header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
                $header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
                $header[] = "Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en;q=0.8";
                $header[] = "Accept-Charset: windows-1251, *;q=0.1";
                $header[] = "Accept-Encoding: deflate, identity, *;q=0";
                $header[] = "Pragma: "; //browsers keep this blank.

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
```

Comment: I'll try that, though I'm not clear on what most of this does. Couple of question though. Its Bulgarian Cyrillic not Russian, so how would this line change for that:

         $header[] = "Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en;q=0.8";

And what do all those q=number mean?

Comment: q=number - well, it's used for preference. you can skip that i think. Try following $header[] = "Accept-Language: bg and for charset  - windows-1251 should work fine